# How to fit a model line in a graph

Tags: r

I tried to create a fitted line through the graph, but it doesn't show at all, it just shows the graph itself. What am I doing wrong here? Check my code below.

```
cor.merged <- cor.merged[order(cor.merged$No.florets), ]
plot(vis.rate ~ No.florets, data = cor.merged[cor.merged$line == 'M',],
     main = "Nectar production vs visitation rate",
     xlab = "No.florets", ylab = "Visitation rate",
     pch = 19)
m1 <- lm(cor.merged$vis.rate[cor.merged$line == 'M'] ~ 
           poly(cor.merged$No.florets[cor.merged$line == 'M'], 2, raw = T))
summary(m1)
lines(cor.merged$No.florets[cor.merged$line == 'M'] ~  
      predict(m1), 
       col = 'red', lwd = 3, type = 'c')
```

Comment: Please provide an example data set or use one that's included in R. `library(help = "datasets")`

Comment: Try flipping your x and y? `lines(predict(M1) ~ cor.merged$No.florets[cor.merged$line == 'M'] , col = 'red', lwd = 3, type = 'c')`

Comment: One could use 'abline(m1)'